# half open socket

Tags: c#, sockets

In node.js, it is possible to have a half-open socket. This means that the socket can become read or write only without closing the whole socket. An example for this:

```
var net = require("net");
net.createServer({allowHalfOpen:true},function(c){
    c.on("data",function(d){
        console.log(d+"");
    });
    c.on("end",function(){
        console.log("ended");
        c.end("thx");
    });
}).listen(888);

var c = net.connect(888,function(){
    c.end("hi");
    c.on("data",function(d){
        console.log(d+"");
    });
    c.on("end",function(){
        console.log("ended");
    });
});
```

Output:

```
hi
ended
thx
ended
```

Is there a way in C# to close only one direction of the socket? Also, is there a way to know if a socket is readable but not writable and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a 'shutdown output' operation in TCP, and there is an API for it in C#. Have another look.

Comment: Oh, true! That's cool. But how can I detect if I can read or write to/from the current socket if the remote socket has closed either the read or the write stream?

Comment: @VanCoding If the other end has shutdown for output, you will get EOS when you read, just as if he had closed the whole connection. What happens if he does shutdown for input depends on his platform (NB not yours). BSD will just throw your data away; Linux will buffer it so you will eventually block when his socket recieve buffer fills up; Windows will send an RST which becomes a 'broken pipe' or 'connection reset by peer' at your end.

Comment: I found out how to determine if the read or the writestream was closed. I can just use the Poll method with the correct SelectMode.

Comment: @VanCoding You can't tell if the peer has shutdown for input without trying a write. There is no network event, so nothing that poll can tell you.